# checkbox default checked="checked" is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

checkbox default checked is not working!
I tried to fix it, but I can not find where is the error here? 
so on page load that is checked, after page loadet that is unchecked!?
I tried that

```
<div class="onoffswitch" style="margin: 0 auto;">
<input type="checkbox" class="avacheckbox onoffswitch-checkbox" id="AvButtonAutoGames" checked="checked"/>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="AvButtonAutoGames">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
</div>
```

and that

```
  <div class="onoffswitch" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="avacheckbox onoffswitch-checkbox" id="AvButtonAutoGames" checked/>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="AvButtonAutoGames">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Actually, Your code it's worked for me for `<input checked />` and check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) also, So what you need exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specify the value, use the checked="true", otherwise do not specify the property.

```html
Checked: <input type="checkbox" checked="true" /><br/>
Not checked: <input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to see, but you're using this syntax to define the checkbox value?

```
document.getElementById('AvButtonAutoGames').checked = true
```

If so, this isn't correct - but in the first JS example you have a correct the `prop` usage:

```
$('#AvButtonAutoGames').prop('checked', true)
```

as in `HTML5`, the syntax to apply is simply `<input checked>` or to expand for clarity `<input checked="checked">`. The absence of the `checked` attribute leads to an unchecked input field.

Simply convert your `.checked=X` to the functional calls and it should work

Answer (score -1):

I think it's worth adding that setting the `checked` attribute will check the box and not allow it to be unchecked by the user.  If the desired functionality is for the checkbox to be checked by default but still able to be unchecked by the user, use the `defaultChecked` attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="AvButtonAutoGames" defaultChecked />
```

or

```
document.getElementById("AvButtonAutoGames").defaultChecked = true;
```