# checkbox default checked="checked" is not working? But why?

Tags: html

When I write an input tag with checked property like

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" />
```

this is not working. i was looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53622539/checkbox-default-checked-checked-is-not-working) and it says checked="true" should be used instead. It really works like that. But why? Any clarification would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute):

> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a
> boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the
> absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
> or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's
> canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes.
> To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted
> altogether.
>
> Here is an example of a checkbox that is checked and disabled. The
> checked and disabled attributes are the boolean attributes.
>
> ```
> <label><input type=checkbox checked name=cheese disabled> Cheese</label>
> ```
>
> This could be equivalently written as this:
>
> ```
> <label><input type=checkbox checked=checked name=cheese disabled=disabled> Cheese</label>
> ```
>
> You can also mix styles; the following is still equivalent:
>
> ```
> <label><input type='checkbox' checked name=cheese disabled=""> Cheese</label>
> ```

The code you say doesn't work, works:

```html
<input type="radio" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" />
```

`checked="true"` works due to error recovery in browsers, but it is wrong and you should not depend on that behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. Actually you were right. It was working. It was just remembering the last checked value on Firefox when I refresh the page. Thats why I thought it wasnt working.. So somehow, I had to cancel autocompletion of my form, and now its all clear